# Various types of compiler optimisations?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, compilation

I have come across loop-unrolling but what other types of compiler optimization are there for C++ code?

If possible, I'd be interested specifically for the Intel Compiler and GNU Compiler.

If I could obtain a list I can google for the explanation upon each type of optimization.

Comment: For gcc, see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: Did you even try to find out if anything exists on the web or not?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_optimization

Comment: Search for "auto vectorization".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are talking generically, beyond loop unrolling, there is also the basic:

1. remove unchanging variables out of a loop.
2. optimizing away unused but initialized objects/variables/instances.(dead code removal)
3. expanding function calls in line, like strlen();
4. using processor specific directives/commands.

thats off the top of my head... I will be back with some scientific (wikipedia lol) answers

heres more:
 5. static variable inlining
 6. complex branch optimization

ok, tired lol heres a decent link i was just looking at :)

http://www.eetimes.com/electronics-products/embedded-tools/4086427/Advanced-Compiler-Optimization-Techniques

Comment: Thanks, fantastic answer- appreciate it!